# Selecting all rows before a certain entry in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to select the rows that before a certain value in the columns first appear?

I have a dataset of user activity and their timestamp recorded as follow:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'user_id':1, 'date':'2017-09-01', 'activity':'Open'},
                   {'user_id':1, 'date':'2017-09-02', 'activity':'Open'}
                   {'user_id':1, 'date':'2017-09-03', 'activity':'Open'}
                   {'user_id':1, 'date':'2017-09-04', 'activity':'Click'}
                   {'user_id':1, 'date':'2017-09-05', 'activity':'Purchase'}
                   {'user_id':1, 'date':'2017-09-06', 'activity':'Open'}
                   {'user_id':1, 'date':'2017-09-07', 'activity':'Open'}
                   {'user_id':2, 'date':'2017-09-04', 'activity':'Open'}
                   {'user_id':2, 'date':'2017-09-06', 'activity':'Purchase'})]
```

Is there a way to select all the rows that happen before the first purchase happen for each user from the data frame? In this example, the desire output will be

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'user_id':1, 'date':'2017-09-01', 'activity':'Open'},
                   {'user_id':1, 'date':'2017-09-02', 'activity':'Open'}
                   {'user_id':1, 'date':'2017-09-03', 'activity':'Open'}
                   {'user_id':1, 'date':'2017-09-04', 'activity':'Click'}
                   {'user_id':2, 'date':'2017-09-04', 'activity':'Open'})]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid explicit apply with

```
In [2862]: df[df['activity'].eq('Purchase').groupby(df['user_id']).cumsum().eq(0)]
Out[2862]:
  activity        date  user_id
0     Open  2017-09-01        1
1     Open  2017-09-02        1
2     Open  2017-09-03        1
3    Click  2017-09-04        1
7     Open  2017-09-04        2
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `groupby` and find all rows which are above the row where a user purchased some item. Then, use the mask to index.

```
df
   activity        date  user_id
0      Open  2017-09-01        1
1      Open  2017-09-02        1
2      Open  2017-09-03        1
3     Click  2017-09-04        1
4  Purchase  2017-09-05        1
5      Open  2017-09-06        1
6      Open  2017-09-07        1
7      Open  2017-09-04        2
8  Purchase  2017-09-06        2

m = df.groupby('user_id').activity\
        .apply(lambda x: (x == 'Purchase').cumsum()) == 0
df[m]

  activity        date  user_id
0     Open  2017-09-01        1
1     Open  2017-09-02        1
2     Open  2017-09-03        1
3    Click  2017-09-04        1
7     Open  2017-09-04        2
```

If your actual data isn't sorted like it is here, you could use `df.sort_values` and make sure it is:

---

```
df = df.sort_values(['user_id', 'date'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.groupby.html) by `mask` with [`DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html), convert to `bool`, invert condition and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
#if necessary
#df = df.sort_values(['user_id', 'date'])
df = df[~df['activity'].eq('Purchase').groupby(df['user_id']).cumsum().astype(bool)]
print (df)
   user_id        date activity
0        1  2017-09-01     Open
1        1  2017-09-02     Open
2        1  2017-09-03     Open
3        1  2017-09-04    Click
7        2  2017-09-04     Open
```

Detail:

```
print (~df['activity'].eq('Purchase').groupby(df['user_id']).cumsum().astype(bool))
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
6    False
7     True
8    False
Name: activity, dtype: bool
```