# transform time series to event window sessions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series, lstm

I have a time series in pandas and want to transform it to a different structure (list of lists) to be useful for a LSTM-based neural network.
I do not want to compute all the sliding windows (like in https://github.com/timeseriesAI/tsai/blob/62e9348d9e29a6b5f628879bd77056c11db5c0ab/tsai/data/preparation.py#L119), rather in a session-minded way only the k=4hours prior a trigger event and put these into the event based window.

```
   import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'region_id':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
    'device_id':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3, 4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4],
    'time_value':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
    'trigger_in_region':[0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1, 0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1, 0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],
    'label': [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1, 0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,]
})

from numpy import random
df['value_1']=random.randint(100, size=(df.shape[0]))
df['value_2']=random.randint(20, size=(df.shape[0]))

display(df.head())
```

In a naive solution I would use:

```
start_points = df[df.trigger_in_region > 0].groupby(['region_id']).time_value.apply(lambda x: list(x))
```

to obtain all the starting points and then in a python for loop (slow, not vectorized) I would compute the desired values.

Is there a more numpy/pandas native way to achieve the same computation faster?

Comment: You said it yourself, it seems the problem is *then in a python for loop (slow, not vectorized)*, not the part that you extract the windows (with groupby, which is fine).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46376302/selecting-all-rows-before-a-certain-entry-in-a-pandas-dataframe seems somewhat similar (but too simplified) here all the data leading up to an event is considered. I only want to handle time bounded data leading up to the event.